# Setup controller title with the string "Settings" not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, title

I'm tring to setup the title for my navigation controller to the text "Settings". I'm testing it in iOS 5.0 and it displays "Item" instead. If I specify any other dummy string (for the Settings key value in my resource bundle file for en) it is displayed correct.

```
[self setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", @"")]];
```

Settings is reserved and could not be specified as the title name for a navigation controller? I know I've tested on 3.X and was displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this...

```
self.navigationItem.title=  @"Some string";
```

Comment: Strange ... it works this way. Using my method if I tried to specify the title as being "My dummy title" worked, but "Settings" not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this has nothing to do with the title, but rather your localization.  `NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", @"")` Tells the system to look up Settings, and if it can't find it in a en.lproj then it will put instead `@""` as a result.  My guess is your localization is incorrect.  `NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", @"Settings")` probably would have worked for you, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
self.title=yourString;
```

Comment: I think Dorin wants it to work in case of localization as well. So your answer is not useful in that sense. Also `[self setTitle:<anyString>];`(which Dorin has used) is not different from `self.title = <anyString>;`.